# What is the meaning of the phrase "National Asset Monetisation Pipeline"?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, banking, budget

Tabling the Union Budget for 2021-22, Ms. Sitharaman said:

> Monetising operating public infrastructure assets is a very important financing option for new infrastructure construction.

This has been taken from a newspaper extract after the budget was discussed. The link to the extract is provided herewith: [Union Budget 2021 | National Asset Monetisation Pipeline to be launched](https://www.thehindu.com/business/budget/union-budget-2021-national-asset-monetisation-pipeline-to-be-launched/article33714786.ece)

However I do not know what it means by the phrase "National Asset Monetisation Pipeline". Please give me a detailed answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asset monetisation is the process of unlocking the value of investment made in public assets which have not yielded appropriate or potential returns so far. The Minister informed that an Asset Monetization dashboard will also be created for tracking the progress and to provide visibility to investors. According to [https://journalsofindia.com/national-asset-monetization-pipeline/#:~:text=Asset%20monetisation%20is%20the%20process,to%20provide%20visibility%20to%20investors](https://journalsofindia.com/national-asset-monetization-pipeline/#:%7E:text=Asset%20monetisation%20is%20the%20process,to%20provide%20visibility%20to%20investors).

Comment: Everything seems fine but why "pipeline"?

Comment: Pipeline meaning continuing. It will continue and it will spread asset monetization.